# Check if any remote upstream exists for a given local repository offline git

Tags: git

I have a local git repository and needs to check if any upstream is linked with this repository. Since I don't need any other details, the command should be lightweight and should work offline.
The command

```
git ls-remote
```

cannot be used, since it checks online. I need a command that doesn't use any network operation.

Comment: Are you looking for `git remote`?

Comment: Thanks just tried git remote and it did work without internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of remotes for a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183724/list-of-remotes-for-a-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+to+list+remotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git remote -v` will list a repository's known remote repositories. It doesn't require a network connection (just tested it myself).

Comment: Thanks just tried git remote and it did work without internet. Earlier wasn't showing the upstream branch, after some change in my setup it's working fine.