# How to see all remote repositories which were currently earlier configured in Github?

Tags: git, github

I want to see all my remote repositories in Github with cmd. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of remotes for a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183724/list-of-remotes-for-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
git remote
```

This will show the names of the remotes accessible from your repo.  If you want to see what the names resolve to you can add the -v option for verbose output:

```
git remote -v
```