# Setting HEAD for each remote via alias

Tags: git

I'm trying to come up with an alias that fetches from all remotes *and* runs `git remote set-head -a [remote]` to set HEAD.

The beginning is pretty easy

```
updateremotes = !git fetch --all && [set-head for all here]
```

For the second part I've been looking at `git for-each-ref`. I have something like this:

```
git for-each-ref --shell --format="git remote set-head %(refname) -a" refs/remotes
```

but I haven't been able to figure out how to only print `origin` and `upstream` instead of all the refs in remote (i.e. all the remote *branches*).

How can this be solved?

**EDIT**:
The use-case is that remote HEADs are only set on clone or an explicit set-head, so it's easy to end up without remote HEADs. If you run `set-head -a` HEAD will be set to the default branch of the remote, so you'll know if it's master/main/dev or whatever.

Comment: You don;t want to list remote branches, you want to list remotes, and only names for remotes (no URL). Do it with `git remote`; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158125/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+remotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that works:

```
fetchall = !git fetch --all && git remote | xargs -i git remote set-head -a {}
```